# Using AVERAGEIF to Determine Month to Date Metrics in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a dashboard that calculates month to date averages for various metrics that are logged in a separate sheet in the same workbook.

This is an example of one of what one of the dashboard components will look like:

[image: Sample Dashboard Widget]

This is a picture of the table I'm populating the data from:

[image: Example Data Table]

So, to populate the month to date average for logistics I'm trying to use the AVERAGEIF function, where I'd like to average the values in the 'Logistics' column if the values in the 'Month' column are equal to the last entered value in that column.  (I know you'd ideally want to check for both month and year, but since the data for this table started at the beginning of the year this is not necessary for now).

I have tried many permutations of the [answers listed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846367/get-average-based-on-value-in-another-row), but none have worked for me and I'm not sure why.

Here are some of the different versions I've tried:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B, 'Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K = LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K))
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B,  LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K))
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B,  LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K), 'Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B)
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B,  'Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K = LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K), 'Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B)
```

**Important**

LastColumnCell is a VBA function I wrote that grabs the last value in a column.

It uses the following code:

**Code:**

```
Function LastColumnCell (arg As Range)
    LastColumnCell = arg.End(xlDown)
End Function
```

So the idea is that if November is the latest month that there's data then it'll average the values in 'Logistics' if the value in the 'Month' column is equal to 11.

All my implementations of the AVERAGEIF function get the `Div/#0` error message, so apparently none of these are evaluating to True, but I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to swap the parameters around as AVERAGEIF takes the range, criteria, [average range] so: `AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K, 'Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K = LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B))` I think as you want to check column K for the date and average column B. I'm not sure if you need your custom function or not as you might choose to use `MAX(K:K)`

Comment: Thank you Max. I do need the function because this will eventually spill into new years with repeating months.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your images, but if I am to assume that:

1.) Column B contains the metrics
2.) Column K contains the month value

...your formula should be:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K,"  LastColumnCell('Daily KPI w Rows'!K:K)",'Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B,MAX('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B),'Daily KPI w Rows'!A:A)
```

There `MAX('Daily KPI w Rows'!B:B)` is to get last entered month of data. Then you dont need to use VBA code.