# How can I find a condtional average in Excel based off a column's value?

Tags: excel

I have data with Four columns: 
Name (A), Sex (B), Year Born (C), Income (D).

What formula could I use to find the average income of all people born in 1995?

This is what I'm trying now: 
=MEDIAN(IF(C:C = 1995, D:D))

But it's not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: two things.  #1, are you confirming the formula as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)?  #2 Don't use full column references with array formulas.  It evaluates all of the cells and if 1,000,000 are blank, you're going to be calculating for a long time.

Comment: You should not be using MEDIAN if you want to find "the average income..."

Answer (score 1):

=AVERAGEIF(C1:C4, "=1995", D1:D4)

[Office Support Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642)

See this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846367/get-average-based-on-value-in-another-row) for more information.